# add character at character count in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

looking to insert special character at specific character count in pyspark string -

```
"M202876QC0581AADMM01"
to
"M-202876-QC0581-AA-DMM01"

(1-6-6-2-)
insertion after 1char then after 6char then after 6char then after 2char
```

Tried something like below but no luck yet.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('M202876QC0581AADMM01',)], ['str'])
(df.withColumn("str", F.regexp_replace(F.col("str") ,  r"(\d{0})(\d{3})(\d{3})" , "$1-$2-$3"))).collect()

Out[121]: [Row(str='M-202-876QC0581AADMM01')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, try this :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame([("M202876QC0581AADMM01",)], ["str"])

pat = r"^(.{1})(.{6})(.{6})(.{2})(.+)"
df = df.withColumn("str", regexp_replace("str", pat, r"$1-$2-$3-$4-$5"))
```

Output :

```
df.show(truncate=False)

+------------------------+
|str                     |
+------------------------+
|M-202876-QC0581-AA-DMM01|
+------------------------+
```